# is there a way to automatically update everything in a mongoose document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

For example I want to update a mongoose document in a put request, I have to do this:

```
app.put('/update', async(req,res) => {
  try{
    const product = await Product.findById(req.body.id)
    product.name = req.body.name
    product.price = req.body.price
    procut.discount = req.body.discount
    // etc...
    await product.save()
    res.json(product)
  }catch(e){
    res.json({message: "Error updating the product"})
  }

})
```

I'm asking if there is another faster and developer friendly way of updating products instead of typing each of the document properties and equal them to the `req.body.[property]`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Try `Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, req.body)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following for object merging

`Object.assign(product, req.body)`

*note*: i haven't tried with mongoose collection

Comment: No, you can not interact with mongoose model this way

Comment: I tried `Object.assign(product, req.body)` and it worked perfectly. but the other one did not work because you change the `product` from a mongoose document to a normal javascript object and therefore `product.save()` will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateMany` or `findOneAndUpdate` model methods, but it is more advisable to use `.save()`

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

If you want to `.save()` to look cleaner, you can do like this:

```
async updateEntity(payload) {
     const keysToUpdate = Object.keys(payload)
     if (keysToUpdate.length === 0) {
         throw new Error('Update payload must not be empty!')
     }
    const entity = await entityModel.findOne({ _id: redirect })
    keysToUpdate.forEach((key) => {
       entity[key] = payload[key]
    })
await entity.save()}
```